# MySql searching for shared values across different rows

Tags: mysql, logging, shared

So I was looking for a possible solution to my problem but could not find it anywhere. I have a log table that logs users' visits (campaign name, IPs, useragent string, hostname etc etc). What I'm trying to get is a list of shared IPs that were seen across the campaigns I define.

so, here is my table for ex:

```
Log
-------------------------------------------------------------------
id             ip                   campaignName       UserName
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   1           173.45.87.2             UK-Test            John
   2           12.45.76.53             Go-4               John
   3           173.45.87.2             Robo-s             John
   4           67.55.33.77             Wrangles           John
   5           3.25.233.53             Stan-Die           John
   6           173.45.87.2             StartMa            John
   7           123.45.67.23            Fresh.Goal         John
   8           54.23.57.86             Ert56              John
   9           173.45.87.2             Yuoit              John
```

Desired output should be:
173.45.87.2

As this IP only appears in all UserName (John) campaigns.

forgot to mention that I know the UserName and all his campaigns, it's just the shared IPs across campaigns that I'm looking for.

Thanks for all helpers

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip
FROM Log
WHERE UserName = 'John'
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```